Replacing double bowl Kitchen Sink drain
To explain, we don't use the underside of the sink area for storage, so didn't know it developed a leak. The leak appears to be in the garbage disposal. I plan to clean up the area, dehumidify and dry, and attempt tightening to be sure. However, the drain elements are original to this home (mobile home) 18 yrs or so ago.
There is nothing great about the drains. We discovered a leak may also be occurring with the line from the dishwasher. So, replacing all of the drains (dishwasher line, too, as it looks extended) isn't a bad idea.
I've looked at various types, and since this is a mobile home, we may replace the double sink coming up with a deeper darker colored one (upgrading the faucet now to a bronze colored one that works a lot better than the original basic one that also has issues).
I notice there are various P-Trap types out there now, and what look like "Cup" trap types? I'm including some images of each that we're considering. This is needing to be done sort of fast and furious, to move on to testing the wiring once dried out to make sure if it has any issues as well requiring repairs.
For this reason, I'm going to attach pictures of each type we are considering, and see if there are any recommendations. We will install a garbage disposal to use for any items that end up going down the drain, and connecting the dishwasher with a new longer hose to deal with that issue as well. On the sink replacement, the current sink is the most basic sink (20 or 22 gauge, 33x19x6 4 hole, with one rusted plugged). When we upgrade the sink, considering an over flow drain, and wanting to know if that's worth the option, or not, for a double bowl kitchen sink with 2 drains, sine the divider will be low enough to allow overflow to the other bowl?
Please provide the reasons pro and con for each type of drain pictured. I will # the images so you can refer to the # for easier reference.
We do have a time constraint, so appreciate any help with this possible.



That's a bit of an ask. For one thing, you've created an XY question with your exclusive list of options. For another, you're requesting lengthy information which may not even be appropriate for you. A much better post would be a simple photo of your sink drain area and "how should I plumb this?" Consider revising to 1) eliminate any irrelevant back story and other commentary, 2) not funnel answers according to your preconceived notions, and 3) show us your sink.

@isherwood - I'm not able to do that. The post will need to stand as is for now. I get what you are saying, but if you can provide the pluses and minuses of each design kit, it would be helpful.

We don't do recommendations of which would be better/best.  Usually the most simple setup is better.  Flex piping/tubing(can clog easier) for drains have their own problems, compared to solid/smooth wall pipes and should be used if the only/best way.  We do help on how to connect the system/parts you decide on using.

Questions that constrain answers to pre-selected options (all of which, in this case, are less than optimal) are often not helpful to the community at large.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

I would not use any of the pictured examples you provided. Those corrugated P-traps/hoses will allow buildup within the lines, leading to the drain backing up. They also are prone to cracking/splitting at the folds.
Kitchen sinks should not have overflows, and every code I know does not allow them. Any sink that deals with organics should not have an overflow as they will allow bacteria to grow within them and pose a health risk. If you find a sink with a built-in overflow, it is not intended for us as a kitchen sink.
I cannot provide details on how I would pipe your setup without a picture of your scenario to know where the drain is situated. I can say that I would, at a minimum, use tubular plastic slip-joint p-trap and components, like in this picture:

(Picture source: Random picture found when googling, from this article about how to install a garbage disposal unit)

+1, I agree that those flex pipes are neither desirable nor necessary. This picture is typical and correct, except that an air gap unit would be used on the dishwasher drain (or at least the drain hose should be routed and secured in a parabolic loop high in the cabinet).
